# Wav file arrayList. Why does this line not work? Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, wav, javasound

I have a string arraylist that goes through this list one by one and its supposed to play the wav file.

On this line "AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(music(x));" music is not recognised, it states 'cannot find symbol'. Also (music.get(x)) does not work. The whole line is then underlined stating its not applicable. What do I need to do? Thanks.

```
    String trackName;

    ArrayList<String> music = new ArrayList();
    music.add("c:\\01.wav");
    music.add("c:\\02.wav");
    music.add("c:\\03.wav");
    music.add("c:\\04.wav");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for(int x = 0; x < music.size(); x++){


      try{

            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(music(x));
            trackName = "The Current Track is " + music.get(x);
            System.out.println(trackName);
            AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
            SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();

      while (ais.available() > 0) {

            int len = ais.read(buffer);
            line.write(buffer, 0, len);

           }

        line.drain(); //wait for the buffer to empty before closing the line
        line.close();

            } 
      catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }   
}
```

Comment: `music(x)` does not make sense as `music` is an ArrayList, try `music.get(x)` and/or use an IDE...

Comment: how can I use music.get(x) correctly in this situation? At the moment attempting this makes the whole line red. As I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your line:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(music(x));
```

to:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(music.get(x)));
```

AudioSystem does not take a string as a parameter to get your audio input stream. It takes either an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29), [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.net.URL%29), or [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.File%29), which I demonstrated above.